# VS2008 SP1 crashes when debugging an XSLT file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xslt, visual-sourcesafe-plugin

I'm using VS2008 SP1 - don't know if this would have happened before I applied SP1 as I never tried it before yesterday. I attempted to debug a fairly simple XSLT file using VS2008 SP1 and got this crash from VS2008 SP1:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

Unexpected error encountered. It is recommended that you restart the application as soon as possible.

Error: Unspecified error

File: vsee\pkgs\vssprovider\sccprj.cpp

Answer (score 3):

Yes, sounds so.
To use it, I had to disable VSS temporarily each time by setting Tools, Options, Source Control, Plug-in selection, Current source control plug-in to "None".

Comment: I use Team System but disabling that in the same way as described here solved the problem.

Comment: I've been having the same problem with VS2010 - any attempt to debug an XSLT led to a crash. Setting 'Current source control plugin' to 'none' in Options>Source Control also worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

We have reproduced this issue and will fix it in the next release of Visual Studio.

You are welcome to use [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) site for reporting any issues related to Visual Studio.

Best regards,
Anton Lapounov
Data Programmability Team @ Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

The same problem, after the stylesheet finishes processing, I get Unspecified error (and eveything seems ok after closing the error message box). Selecting source control plugin to "None" in VS options gets rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link to Microsoft's bug and "fix" report, which includes info on the work around (disabling your source control plugin): [VS2008 sp1 - XSLT Debugging Error in sccprj.cpp](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/366646/vs2008-sp1-xslt-debugging-error-in-sccprj-cpp)